# Simple Regex freeze app

Tags: java, android, regex

I want to check whether a text contains phone numbers or domains. Previously, I remove all spaces. If there are no hits the app freezes. Why?

```
String aboutText = about.getText().toString();
String aboutTextClear = aboutText.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
Matcher phone = Patterns.PHONE.matcher(aboutTextClear);
Matcher domain = Patterns.DOMAIN_NAME.matcher(aboutTextClear);
if(phone.find() || domain.find()) {
    return;
}
```

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/util/Patterns.java

Comment: Useless without the PHONE and DOMAIN_NAME regex....

Comment: @rolfl https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/util/Patterns.java

Comment: Yeah.... no. the regexes look 'OK', I think it is something that happens after the `if()`. Use your debuger and figure out whether non-matches actually complete the pattern search.

Comment: I think there is a problem with Patterns.DOMAIN_NAME. If I use the same code only with Patterns.PHONE or with Patterns.PHONE and Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS there are no crash. Unfortunately, there is also no exception, the app simply freez, sometimes even the whole OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a large string value, the DOMAIN could in fact take a long time to match. Removing the spaces from before the match makes things a lot worse, because now potential domain names can be much bigger.... long sequences of space-less text would create a lot of backtracking for negative hits on the TLD part of it.

I would consider splitting the input in to 'known' smaller chunks using a simpler expression, and then matching on the smaller parts. This will reduce the scope for issues in back-tracked regex.

So, since the phone number regex is simpler, and the IPAddress is even simpler still, I would do it in three stages, and leave the domain name for last (preferably strip the IP address part from the expression if you can...)

This of course assumes the input text is large, but, doing something like:

```
Matcher phone = Patterns.PHONE.matcher(aboutText); // no space manipulation...
if (phone.find()) {
    return;
}
for (String word : aboutText.split("\\s+")) {
    Matcher ipaddress = Patterns.IP_ADDRESS.matcher(aboutText); // no space manipulation...
    if (ipaddress.find()) {
        return;
    }

    Matcher domain = Patterns.DOMAIN_NAME.matcher(aboutTextClear);
    if(domain.find()) {
        return;
    }
}
```